# Dynamic SVG Parameters yields only "?"

Tags: labeling, attribute-table, svg

I have a folder with SVG files, which have the same name before the .svg extension as objects in a corresponding field of the attribute table of a point layer (place_town). I want to add specific city-arms like symbols per town. In the symbology panel under the option "Dynamic SVG parameters", I clicked on the data defined override icon on the right and selected Edit. This opened the expression editor where I typed in the '/correct path to the svg folder/' ||  "corresponding field"  ||  '.svg'. In the preview I can scroll through all objects and see the correct name. Yet, after "OK", I see only question marks throughout.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Since this seems like a character set issue. please [Edit] the Question to specify the character set(s) involved.

Comment: The question marks indicate that QGIS can't find the SVG symbol. This seem to indicate that your expression return a wrong path. Could you show us the exact full expression and the return value ? Are you sure that the "corresponding field" value exactly match the SVG file name ?

Comment: 'home/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/svg/' ||  "name_GL"  ||  '.svg'

Comment: In the meantime, I have placed my SVG folder in the user default folder under settings > options > system. I can see the symbols in the SVG browser of layer properties panel. I changed the path accordingly to 'home/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/svg/' ||  "name_GL"  ||  '.svg' (this is pasted from the data defined override panel). Yes I have checked the spelling identity of the names.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the issue still exists